# Laravel 8 pivot working only in 1 direction

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I got a problem I have done model and migration for 3 tables: movies, actors and actor_movie (pivot)

when Im using from model Actor method movie() it working but don't work from Movie using actor()

[image]

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function actors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Actor::class, 'actor_movie');
    }
}

class Actor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function movies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Movie::class, 'actor_movie');
    }

}
```

movies migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('movies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

actor migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('actors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Pivot migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('actor_movie', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('movie_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('movie_id')->references('id')->on('movies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->bigInteger('actor_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('actor_id')->references('id')->on('actors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->primary(['actor_id', 'movie_id']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
```

Comment: does Movie model has belongsToMany Actor?

Comment: yes, added a screen

Comment: Don't post images of code, add the code to your question

Comment: Add the pivot table name as second parameter of your belongsToMany function.

Comment: https://medium.com/@afrazahmad090/laravel-many-to-many-relationship-explained-822b554c1973

Comment: Can you share the migrations?

Comment: @GertB. done, and shared code still same output

Comment: @RuiCosta shared

Comment: @JakubKrakowiak What does it say when you `var_dump($movie->actors)` ?

Comment: @HuyPhạm it says NULL

Comment: Do you have the laravel debugbar installed? in that case you can look at the queries. the code above should work.

Comment: @JakubKrakowiak Have you tried drop the database and re-run the migrations? Your code should be functioning

Comment: Ill try do it but ive done it one time with No success. I’ll try also debugbar in a moment

Comment: Isn't there an eager loading only on the Actor model like the public $with attribute ? Anyway using $movie->actors() in the foreach should do the trick or calling $movie->load('actors') before using $movie->actors

Comment: @ZarkDev when I'm writing load I got this respond Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [actors] on model [App\Models\Movie].'

Comment: @steven7mwesigwa yes I got a data here, for example actor 3 is in movie 2,3,4

Comment: @JakubKrakowiak Well this is unexpectedly weird.. If your code is exactly as pasted it should work, maybe you have some PHP OPcache madness going on ? Maybe try `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Ohh, I see you make your test in a tinker console ? Maybe you need to kill tinker and restart it for your code to be updated when you save your files ? (I'm not familiar with tinker)

Comment: @ZarkDev Ohh I missed it, ur right it works, thanks for ur time and help

Comment: Don't forget to check the answer to help people with the same issue get to the solution quicker :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you are running your tests in a Tinker console.
Tinker console loads all your PHP files and dependencies on startup and keep them in memory.

For your code to be refreshed, you need to **kill tinker and restart it**